# having problems parsing gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to parse data from here http://api.sfpark.org/sfpark/rest/availabilityservice?response=json&pricing=yes

in particular this part

```
RATES: {
 RS: [
      {
          BEG: "12:00 AM",
          END: "2:00 AM",
          RATE: "0",
          RQ: "No charge"
      },
      {
          BEG: "2:00 AM",
          END: "6:00 AM",
          RATE: "0",
          RQ: "Str sweep"
      },
      {
          BEG: "6:00 AM",
          END: "12:00 AM",
          RATE: "0",
          RQ: "No charge"
      }
  ]
},
```

and I have this code

```
if (dataObject.getAsJsonObject("RATES").isJsonObject()){
  JsonObject rates = dataObject.getAsJsonObject("RATES");
  if (rates.getAsJsonArray("RS").isJsonArray()){
      //parse stuff
  }
}
```

I get com.google.gson.JsonObject cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray in here

```
 if (rates.getAsJsonArray("RS").isJsonArray())
```

and If I change that to

```
if (rates.getAsJsonObject("RS").isJsonObject())
```

I get com.google.gson.JsonArray cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Comment: FYI, you are not using GSON here. That is a separate Google library: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Comment: run it through the debugger but use rates.get("RS") and see what type of element it returns

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified the link for your API, you could do the following:

Firstly, head to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and dump your API there, it will generate the necessary POJO classes for you.

Set the configurations of the website to the following:

[image]

Based on your API, it generate the following:

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@Expose
private String STATUS;
@SerializedName("NUM_RECORDS")
@Expose
private String NUMRECORDS;
@Expose
private String MESSAGE;
@SerializedName("AVAILABILITY_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP")
@Expose
private String AVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP;
@SerializedName("AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP")
@Expose
private String AVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP;
@Expose
private List<com.example.AVL> AVL = new ArrayList<com.example.AVL>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The STATUS
*/
public String getSTATUS() {
return STATUS;
}

/**
* 
* @param STATUS
* The STATUS
*/
public void setSTATUS(String STATUS) {
this.STATUS = STATUS;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The NUMRECORDS
*/
public String getNUMRECORDS() {
return NUMRECORDS;
}

/**
* 
* @param NUMRECORDS
* The NUM_RECORDS
*/
public void setNUMRECORDS(String NUMRECORDS) {
this.NUMRECORDS = NUMRECORDS;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The MESSAGE
*/
public String getMESSAGE() {
return MESSAGE;
}

/**
* 
* @param MESSAGE
* The MESSAGE
*/
public void setMESSAGE(String MESSAGE) {
this.MESSAGE = MESSAGE;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The AVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP
*/
public String getAVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP() {
return AVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP;
}

/**
* 
* @param AVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP
* The AVAILABILITY_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP
*/
public void setAVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP(String AVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP) {
this.AVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP = AVAILABILITYUPDATEDTIMESTAMP;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The AVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP
*/
public String getAVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP() {
return AVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP;
}

/**
* 
* @param AVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP
* The AVAILABILITY_REQUEST_TIMESTAMP
*/
public void setAVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP(String AVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP) {
this.AVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP = AVAILABILITYREQUESTTIMESTAMP;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The AVL
*/
public List<com.example.AVL> getAVL() {
return AVL;
}

/**
* 
* @param AVL
* The AVL
*/
public void setAVL(List<com.example.AVL> AVL) {
this.AVL = AVL;
}

}
```

Next, do the following:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 Example example = gson.fromJson(response, Example.class);
```

Here response is the network response you get.

This is something I do on a regular basis when dealing with API requests. I hope this helps you out too :)